# Linux File Logs

Tags: linux, file, logging

I need to view a log of files that have been opened, surely there are logs stored for this, but I have not been able to find them in the /var/log/ directory.

Thanks, Dave

Answer (score 1):

There is no such log by default. Use the audit subsystem to detect when files have been opened.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'lsof' to see what files your user has opened, per process id.

Comment: Perhaps you mean file auditing?  You can google SELinux and find examples for that.